# hoew do I perform these Unix commands

Tags: unix, command

I'm currently in a Unix programming course. I have a commands sheet and I can't figure out what command will delete all files in a directory ending in an x or a y. And what conditions need to be met for cd b/c/d/e and cd d/e to move to the same directory.

Comment: @BernardSaucier: Why regular expressions? File matching patterns are sufficient. The `*x` in `rm *x` is not a regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

For your first problem, you can:

"`cd`" to your directory

then "`rm *x`" and "`rm *y`", or "`rm *x *y`".

As for your second question, about conditions:

"`cd`" is short for "change directory".  It doesn't move files, per se.